# docker-compose + nuxt で localhost:3000でアクセス出来ない。

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nuxt.js

いつもお世話になっております。
現在、docker + nuxtの開発環境を構築しようと思い、[こちら](https://qiita.com/fussy113/items/ed7f56ff647a7f853bc9)などを参考に環境を作成いたしました。
ただ、ホスト側からlocalhost:3000でアクセスすると下記のようにエラーが返ってきて接続が出来ません・・・。

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:3000/'
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

色々なサイトを見て調べたりしたのですが、原因がわからずに困っております。
原因をご教授頂けませんでしょうか。

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  nuxt:
    build: ./Dockerfiles/nuxt
    container_name: shaken_tech_nuxt
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html/client
    command: bash -c "yarn dev && /bin/bash"
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      PORT: 3000
      HOST: 0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10.19-alpine

# install libraries
RUN apk add --update \
    bash \
    make \
    git \
    curl \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN npm update -g npm
```

package.json

```
  …省略
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
  },
  …省略
```

nuxt.config.js

```
export default {
  mode: 'spa',
  // server: {
  //   port: 3000,
  //   host: '0.0.0.0'
  // },
  …省略
}
```

## 試した事

### 1.docker経由じゃなくホスト側で `yarn dev`をする

→ http://localhost:3000 で正常にアクセスが出来、nuxtの初期画面を表示させる事ができました。

### 2.ゲスト側にログインしてcurlをしてみる

docker-compose.yml の environmentに設定している `HOST`の設定のあるなしで挙動が変わる。

#### `HOST`設定無しの場合

`yarn dev`すると、`Listening on: http://localhost:3000/`と表示される。
その状態で別ターミナルでゲスト側にログインしてcurlを実行

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:3000/'
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused
```

その状態で別ターミナルでホスト側にログインしてcurlを実行

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:3000/'
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

#### `HOST`設定有りの場合

`yarn dev`すると、`Listening on: http://172.18.0.3:3000/`と表示される。
※ IPはdockerを立ち上げるたびにかわる。
その状態で別ターミナルでゲスト側にログインしてcurlを実行

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:3000/'
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused

$ curl 'http://172.18.0.3:3000/'
<!doctype html>
<html >
HTMLが表示される
</html>
```

その状態で別ターミナルでホスト側にログインしてcurlを実行

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:3000/'
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

### 3.package.jsonのscriptのdevの記述を変更

下記の記載方法だったものを変更してみました。

```
"dev": "nuxt",
```

↓

```
"dev": "NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0 NUXT_PORT=3000 nuxt",
```

[nuxtのドキュメント](https://ja.nuxtjs.org/faq/host-port/)に記載のあるように`HOST`と`NUXT_HOST`の両方試してみて、ホスト側でcurlをしても同じ結果でした。

### 4. nuxt.config.jsの`server`に`host`などを設定してみる

[nuxtのドキュメント](https://ja.nuxtjs.org/faq/host-port/)に記載のあるように試してみたのですが、ホスト側でcurlをしても同じ結果でした。

再現環境

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea
$ docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.25.4, build 8d51620a
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15.3
BuildVersion:   19D76
```

ESETをインストールしていますが、firewallは切ってテストをしているので、その辺りのネットワーク周りでも無いと思っております。

https://web.plus-idea.net/on/docker-web-server-access-denied/
こちらなどを参考に一つずつチェックをしてみたのですが、ゲスト側から`curl 'http://localhost:3000/'`しても`Connection refused`のエラーが出るのが悪いのかなと思ってはいるのですが、その解決策がわからない状況です。

解決法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授頂けませんでしょうか。
何卒、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

同じサイトを参考にしました．

サイトには記載されていませんが、 telemetry について聞かれる部分があり、そこで y/n を答えないと起動しなかったと思います．

[https://github.com/nuxt/telemetry](https://github.com/nuxt/telemetry%E3%80%80)　
の下部にある通り、

```
telemetry: false
```

を nuxt.config.js に追加すると telemetry を聞かれなくなるので、 docker-compose で yarn dev が実行されても立ち上がると思います．